# move element from an xml file to another xml element using xslt-3

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

Given the following example xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <catalog>
           <book id="bk101">
              <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
              <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
              <genre>Computer</genre>
              <price>44.95</price>
              <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
              <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
              with XML.</description>
           </book>
           <book id="bk102">
              <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
              <title>Midnight Rain</title>
              <genre>Fantasy</genre>
              <price>5.95</price>
              <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
              <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
              an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
              of the world.</description>
           </book>
           <book id="bk103">
              <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
              <genre>Fantasy</genre>
              <price>5.95</price>
              <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
              <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
              society in England, the young survivors lay the 
              foundation for a new society.</description>
           </book>
        </catalog>
```

I need to merge all title elements into the author element, by a rule:
If the author element already exists, then the title element's value will be inserted in the author record, using a separator ie a | character.
If there is not an author element in the record, the title element would become the author element.
Desired output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <catalog>
           <book id="bk101">
              <author>Gambardella, Matthew | XML Developer's Guide</author>
              <genre>Computer</genre>
              <price>44.95</price>
              <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
              <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
              with XML.</description>
           </book>
           <book id="bk102">
              <author>Ralls, Kim | Midnight Rain</author>
              <genre>Fantasy</genre>
              <price>5.95</price>
              <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
              <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
              an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
              of the world.</description>
           </book>
           <book id="bk103">
              <author>Maeve Ascendant</author>
              <genre>Fantasy</genre>
              <price>5.95</price>
              <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
              <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
              society in England, the young survivors lay the 
              foundation for a new society.</description>
           </book>
        </catalog>
```

How the above result could be achieved using xslt-3?

Comment: Where is the attempt that you have made?

Comment: the attempt is done using xslt-2, while the question is about xslt-3

Comment: So where is your attempt to use xslt-3? Or are you expecting someone to write it entirely for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is strip the existing `author` element and replace the `title` element with a new `author` element.

The value of the new `author` element would be a string-join of the original `author` (if it exists) and the current `title` value separated by `|`.

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="author"/>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <author>
      <xsl:value-of select="string-join((../author,.),' | ')"/>
    </author>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: This would work as XSLT 2.0 too if you replaced `xsl:mode` with the [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copying).